# Does a C# property setter not get called when value set via Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a complex recursive reflection logic written where an entity property is being set via reflection. But i can see that the setter of that particular is not called.

Is this possible..? If yes, is there a way to make the setter for the property to run. (I am aware, that getter and setters are essentially functions in their inner implementation)

Comment: What do you mean by "the setter for the setter"? It sounds like you may be setting the *fields* by reflection instead of the properties. If you want to call the property setters, just use the properties instead of the fields. A [mcve] would definitely help to clarify this question.

Comment: How do you see that? If you are setting property, the setter is always called. It doesn't matter if it is through code or through reflection.